# vspscc file in .NET Core project appears checked out despite not being source-controlled

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, tfvc

I have a solution under TFVC with (among other things) two .NET 7.0 projects.

- Both of these projects have a .vspscc file
- Neither of these .vspscc file is under source control

  - They don't appear in Source Control Explorer
  - When I right-click them in the Solution Explorer, the only Source-Control-related option is "Add files to Source Control"
- Neither of the files has the read-only attribute (they both have the Archive attribute)

Yet, when I open the solution, one of them shows the red check mark of a checked-out file, and the other does not. This is distracting, falsely hinting at pending chances, and **I cannot "undo" it** because it is not under source control (and from reading here it should not be).

How do I get rid of this falsely checked-out status?

Comment: Hey, I'm facing the same annoying issue. I wonder if you ever solved this?

Comment: No I didn't. :-(